# Chat client on Mobile

Tags: mobile, client, chat

We have to develop a chat client for mobile. The devices should be for the following:

Android
iPhone
Blackberry
Symbian
Windows mobile
Windows CE
Palm

Which technology we should use for the multiple OS computability. We like the most of code common. 
This chat client also support the video and audio chat.

Answer (score 0):

Android and BlackBerry: Java
Symbian and Win Mo: C++
iPhone and Palm: Objective C and C

It is possible from to write the apps so that some common functionality can be reused, but it needs careful design. But you are a bit out of luck on this.

I would recommend starting with Java and Objective C implementations as this will get you Android, BlackBerry and iPhone, which have a lot more traction in market than other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Look at cross platform frameworks like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - that way you can keep the UI and as much code as you care to port to JavaScript common, then do the remaining in native code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently React Native framework gains popularity as a solution for implementing JavaScript based apps for Android and iOS platforms. Here is a guide for [React Native](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native).

JavaScript SDK can be also used for preparing desktop app for Windows via Electron for example.

Since you need to cover a lot of platforms, you might need also a backend solution providing an API option to cover all your needs.

Try ConnectyCube. It has React Native support in its JS SDK and provides API to cover the rest of cases. So, it's flexible enough and you can use it for developing apps for all your platforms.